# Oscilloscope probe measure squarewave

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

As I was trying to validate our pcb design, I measured the impedance matching on the digital transmission lines, and got stuck with the oscilloscope not showing what I expected. We are using the PicoScope 4227, but I suspect that the strange measurement is not directly related to the specific oscilloscope but more to general on how to measure digital signals.

My setup is as follow:
I measure the output-pin of an FPGA with both oscilloscope input A and B.

Input A (blue) is measured using the oscilloscope probe set to x10.

Input B (red) is measured using a 50-ohm coxial cable terminated at the scope input with 50-ohm.

As you can see, Input B seems correct, no reflection ect.

But Input A (the probe) has some overshoot, and ringing.

The probe should be calibrated and valid to 250MHz, so I don't get was is wrong. ?

I suspect that the small probe-clip adds some inductance, and therefore we see the ringing. But I really don't know.

[image: oscilloscope screenshot]

**EDIT**
After reading your answers, I walked got into our lab storage and started looking, and found a probe GND clip like the one showed in the answer below.

When I use that clip, I get the output below. Which is really a huge improvement.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this is typical when your ground connection is not suitable for the frequencies you're working with. You may want to use a ground spring to reduce both the inductance-related peak and the noise:

[image]

Comment: In have tried moving the ground clip even further away from the signal measured with the probe and can see that the ringing gets worse (as expected).

Comment: You where completely right, the GND clip was the issue. In have edit my answer with new picture.

Comment: @JakobJ Hey, I'm glad you have found that GND clip and it helped!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I suspect that blue is a probe problem - maybe a slightly displaced ground connection forming a small inductive loop that resonates with the probe capacitance producing ringing when hit with a fast transient. Red shows some small signs of not being perfectly terminated (nearly gets there first time) but is fine for data.

Comment: Have you tried 'tuning', or compensating the probe? There should be a trimmer in the housing for that.

Comment: @F.Bloggs yes I always take care of this but maybe you should address this comment to the OP or make your own answer.

Comment: You where completely correct.

Comment: @Andy - sorry, yes, that was directed at the OP. I see I posted my comment in the wrong place! Oops.